# curl upload command using bash & terminal

Tags: bash, curl, dropbox, dropbox-api

when i use bash to upload files to dropbox, it works fine but when i manually use command line it does not work.

I'm thinking it might be the & in the url.. im not sure..

Bash code:

```
CURL_BIN="/usr/bin/curl"
#Note: This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers.
#CURL_ACCEPT_CERTIFICATES="-k"
CURL_PARAMETERS="--progress-bar"
APPKEY="zrwv8z3bycfk3m8"
OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN="aaaaaaaa"
APPSECRET="aaaaaaaaaa"
OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET="aaaaaaaaa"
ACCESS_LEVEL="dropbox"
API_UPLOAD_URL="https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put"
RESPONSE_FILE="temp2.txt"
FILE_SRC="temp.txt"

$CURL_BIN $CURL_ACCEPT_CERTIFICATES $CURL_PARAMETERS -v -i -o "$RESPONSE_FILE" --upload-file "$FILE_SRC" "$API_UPLOAD_URL/$ACCESS_LEVEL/$FILE_DST?oauth_consumer_key=$APPKEY&oauth_token=$OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_signature=$APPSECRET%26$OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"
```

Manual code:

```
curl --insecure --progress-bar -v -i -o temp2.txt --upload-file temp.txt https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/attachments/temp.txt?oauth_consumer_key=aaaaaaaaaa&oauth_token=aaaaaaaaa&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_signature=aaaaaaaaa%26aaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: what happens when you replace `&` with `&amp`?

Comment: doesn't work. i output the code it shows that in manual mode, once it reaches &, it will stop there..

Comment: What's result/error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl --insecure --progress-bar -v -i -o temp2.txt --upload-file temp.txt "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/attachments/temp.txt?oauth_consumer_key=aaaaaaaaaa&oauth_token=aaaaaaaaa&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_signature=aaaaaaaaa%26aaaaaaaaaa"
```

The solution is to add in the inverted commas "